# Приближенна/приближена

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Одна или две буквы **н** нужны в выделенном слове?

Программа максимально *приближена* к потребностям заказчиков.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Программа максимально приближена к потребностям заказчиков.

Пояснение

Краткие причастия, действительно, всегда пишутся с одной буквой Н, но их нужно отличать от парных отпричастных прилагательных, например:нитки запутаны – жизнь очень сложна и запутанна.

Как раз наличие наречия степени "максимально" может послужить причиной сомнения, но причастие "приближенный" не имеет парного прилагательного "приближенный".

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Программа максимально приближеНа к потребностям заказчиков.

Comment: Прежде всего, давайте разберемся, что такое приближена. Существует глагол приблизить (совершенный вид). Раз глагол совершенного вида, то в его форме причастия будут писаться две НН: приблизить — приближенная. Теперь о кратком причастии. В кратких причастиях пишется одна Н абсолютно в любых случаях: Программа написана (краткое причастие) нашим разработчиком.

Answer (score 0):

Это краткая форма причастия *приближенный*. В кратких причастиях пишется одно Н.